# How to create aligned array of array c++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to create an aligned array which will be composed of other arrays. I know how to do it with `std::vector<>`, but the method with vector is not suitable for me.

Many thanks in advance to those who will be able to help me.

Here is an example what I want to do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
    std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
// Prints 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10...15   

int m = 5;

for (int i = 0; i < m ; ++i) {
    float* varr[i] = (float*) aligned_alloc(32, sizeof(float)*8); 

    int k = i*8;

    varr[i] = {arr[k+0], arr[k+1], arr[k+2], arr[k+3], arr[k+4], arr[k+5], arr[k+6], arr[k+7]};
}

    varr[0] = {arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], arr[4], arr[5], arr[6], arr[7]};   
    // Prints: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

    varr[1] = {arr[8], arr[9], arr[10], arr[11], arr[13], arr[14], arr[15], arr[16]}; 
    // Prints: 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15

    varr[2] = .....;
    varr[3] = .....;
    varr[4] = .....;
```

Comment: What's wrong with the `std::vector` variant?

Comment: Initially I have an array which has to by splitted in arrays consisting of 8 members to load into avx register _mm256_load_ps(varr). All array data must be aligned. When I did it using vector I lost an alignment and storing data back _mm256_store_ps(arr,varr[i].vector)  compilation gave me an error (core dumped). Even when I used aligned allocator to align vector.

Comment: Can't you use vector of [aligned_storage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) ?

Comment: Does you solution not work? What's the issue exactly?

Comment: Show the code work the vector. Maybe we can fix that for you.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I am not sure of avx instructions, but my modified approach will be like this:

```
int main (){

    int dim1{5}, dim2{8};

    float* varr = static_cast<float*> (aligned_alloc(sizeof(float)*dim1*dim2, sizeof(float)*dim1*dim2));

     for (int i = 0; i < dim1 ; ++i) {

         for (int j = 0; j < dim2; ++j) {
             varr[i*dim2+j] =i*dim2 + j;
         }
     }

     for (int i = 0; i < dim1 ; ++i) {
         for (int j = 0; j < dim2; ++j) {
             std::cout << &varr[i*dim2+j] << ",";
         }
         std :: cout << "\n";
     }
return 0;
}
```

It basically uses the logic of allocating /accessing the array in one big chunk of pure 1D array

Another approach will be using a pointer to a pointer like below:

```
#include <iostream>

int main (){

    int dim1{5}, dim2{8};

    float** varr = static_cast<float**> (aligned_alloc(sizeof(float*)*dim1, sizeof(float*)*dim1));
    for(int i=0; i<dim1; ++i){
        varr[i] = static_cast<float*> (aligned_alloc(sizeof(float)*dim2, sizeof(float)*dim2));
    }

     for (int i = 0; i < dim1 ; ++i) {

         for (int j = 0; j < dim2; ++j) {
             varr[i][j] = 0.1 + static_cast<float>(i*dim2 + j);
         }
     }

     for (int i = 0; i < dim1 ; ++i) {
         for (int j = 0; j < dim2; ++j) {
             std::cout << &varr[i][j] << ",";
         }
         std :: cout << "\n";
     }
return 0;
}
```

But the issue with this is that the memory is not aligned across the first dimension, `dim1` .

Comment: The question is specifically about aligned arrays, so this doesn't answer it.

Comment: why do you say so? the memory is completely aligned in a 1D array. As far as I get from the question, the author wants to have  all the data in a 1D array but access them using a 2D pattern.

Comment: The question's summary specifies "aligned" data, and the code's use of `aligned_alloc` makes it clear that it refers to a non-standard alignment. The comments further make it clear that the OP needs to use SIMD (AVX) instructions on the array content.

Comment: I've solved it allready. I was did some stupid mistake using vector implementation. Now it work's. 
Suggestion of gajendra's solution is very intresting. I think I will try to  to use your suggestion. Thank's to all.

Comment: if you think my solution is useful, can you then please accept my answer and/or upvote it , and maybe post what worked for you so that  others in the community may benefit too